# When i opened a .xml in eclipse its large-hdpi,normal-hdpi,large-mdpi.xml files also opened along with it?

Tags: android, xml

Why did other xml files along with it opened.So every time when i click that xml file all the corresponding different screen size xml files also opens along with it.This slows my eclipse[image]

How to avoid this?Is this eclipse problem?

Comment: Did u restart eclipse?

Comment: Ya every time when i open this xml ,other xml files also opens along with it.

Comment: Keep a back up of the following xmls: **large-hdpi\home_en.xml**, **normal-hdpi\home_en.xml**, **large-mdpi\home_en.xml**, and then delete these xmls: **large-hdpi\home_en.xml**, **normal-hdpi\home_en.xml**, **large-mdpi\home_en.xml**