# What are the different screensizes we should concentrate while developing app?

Tags: android, xml, screen-size

I received a project where there are many screensizes.
[image: screensizes]

So everytime i make changes in the xml's in the layout folder,i have to change the xml code in different layout-screensize folder.Is there any other simple ways.Also another problem occurs while oepning the layout xml,other screen size xml also opens along with it and my eclipse gets stuck.I have mentioned the prob here.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164017/when-i-opened-a-xml-in-eclipse-its-large-hdpi-normal-hdpi-large-mdpi-xml-files)

Answer (score 0):

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

This should have some info on screen sizes but I suggest using fragments for scaling your layouts, this way you would only have to change one file :)

Here's a link for that as well 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Android dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). There you will find updated information about what Android versions are most used right now (usually the last month). The same goes for screens. You should concentrate first on the most used.